# Adjacent sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Could any one please tell me how to prove that these two sequences are adjacent ($a_n$) and ($b_n$) and then find their common limit;
Given that:
$a_{n+1}$=(1/2)($a_n$+$b_n$) and $b_{n+1}$=(2 $a_n$$b_n$)/($a_n$+$b_n$)
With 0 <$b_1$<$a_1$

Comment: What are "adjacent sequences"?

Comment: It looks like arithmetico-harmonic means, in that case it should converge to geometric mean.

Comment: Two sequences are adjacent if one is increasing ,the other is decreasing    and the limit of their difference is zero

Comment: Show that $a_nb_n$ is a constant sequence.